# Azure AD Join with PowerShell on Windows 10+ (Automated)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-3.0, microsoft-graph-intune

Is there still really no way to automate joining a Windows device to Azure AD via Powershell? I've looked and tried just about everything. The only methods I know of are below.

Self-service: Windows OOBE or Settings

Bulk enrollment

Windows Autopilot

Comment: Is there anyway to call the Azure AD Join Wizard directly?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no powershell script/commandlet that can auto join with AAD.

Apart from three method which you have mentioned there is also one more method i.e., [Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/enroll-a-windows-10-device-automatically-using-group-policy#troubleshoot-auto-enrollment-of-devices) you can make use of it.

You can also [view this to decide how to plan for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/azureadjoin-plan)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/261596/add-computer-to-azure-ad-step-by-step.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using automation in PowerShell. The perquisite is you need the credential of a user access to the window device and the credentials of a domain administrator. If you have the credentials, Then this can be done using:

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName Server01 -LocalCredential Server01\Admin01 -DomainName Domain02 -Credential Domain02\Admin02 -Restart -Force
```

and removed using:

```
Remove-Computer -ComputerName Server01 -UnjoinDomaincredential Domain01\Admin01 -PassThru -Verbose -Restart
```